# Feed importer View

Tags: nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

I have created a Feed Importer with CSV as Parser and Proccesor as Self Node processor which is attached to a content type. The feed works fine when importing to the content type, however I would like to create a Table View that displays the imported feed. Can someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how in views but how would I make it so the view table include all of my feed importers, for example csv, xml, etc.